# Moving pictures with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I have a problem with [my site](http://www.lacasadelholandes.es/en/), or at least I think I have. I use a very simple nearly recursive Javascript function to move two pictures. However, on my four year old computer, this is not a smooth movement. I've reduced the size of the pictures, but...

The code is not recursive as I use setTimeout between calls.

The code is the following:
(onload)

```
sImgArray = ["imgLaVera", "imgAlmanzor", "imgRosarito", "imgBaile"];
iImg = sImgArray.length - 1;
setTimeout('playShow(0,' + iImg + ')', 4000);

function playShow(iVisible, iImgs)
{
    if( iVisible < iImgs )
        iLeft = iVisible + 1;
    else
        iLeft = 0;

    imgLeft = document.getElementById(sImgArray[iLeft]);
    imgLeft.style.left = "-" + imgLeft.width + "px";
    playMove(-imgLeft.width, iVisible, iImgs);
}
function playMove(i, iVisible, iImgs)
{
    if( iVisible < iImgs )
        iLeft = iVisible + 1;
    else
        iLeft = 0;

    imgLeft = document.getElementById(sImgArray[iLeft]);
    imgRight = document.getElementById(sImgArray[iVisible]);

    if( i < 0 )
    {
        i = i + 5;
        imgLeft.style.left = (i - 2) + "px";
        imgRight.style.left = (i + imgLeft.width) + "px";
        setTimeout('playMove(' + i + ', ' + iVisible + ',' + iImgs + ')', 75);
    }
    else
    {
        if( iVisible < iImgs )
            iVisible = iVisible + 1;
        else
            iVisible = 0;
        setTimeout('playShow(' + iVisible + ',' + iImgs + ')', 4000)
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: 'nearly' recursive?  is that like 'sort of' pregnant?

Comment: Hahaha, I guess, sort of. I should have known I was writing for an educated audience. +1 for laughs.

Comment: Also, I avoided recursive because I didn't want to cog the web browsers that visit my site.

Comment: Maybe there is nothing wrong with the code... but how can I improve the graphics? My laptop is four year old, by no means a modern machine, but it should be able to handle my site without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following settings in `playMove` will give you what you want:

```
i = i + 1;
setTimeout('playMove( ... )', 15);
```

Your animation seemes sluggish because you're changing image positions **rarely** and with ***big jumps***. If you want it to be **smoother** you should change the positions more **frequently** but less pixels in each step.

```
Old: 5 px / 75 ms
New: 1 px / 15 ms
```

---

*Sidenotes*

If you really care for speed, don't select elements in every call of the rendering function (`playMove`).
Do this at the end of `show`before calling `setTimeout`:

```
// select elements by their id and replace them in the array
for (var i = sImgArray.length; i--;) {
  sImgArray[i] = document.getElementById( sImgArray[i] );
}
```

Now you can simply write

```
sImgArray[iLeft]
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById(sImgArray[iLeft])
```

in playMove and playShow.

Secondly you should try to avoid passing functions as textual parameters because they need to be evaled separately.

```
// GOOD
setTimeout(function() {
    playShow(iVisible, iImgs);
}, 4000);

// BAD
setTimeout('playShow(' + iVisible + ',' + iImgs + ')', 4000)
```

Thirdly this is like the ugliest thing I've seen in my life:

```
setTimeout('show.call(\'index\');', 6000);
```

Don't use the `this` reference to pass parameter to a function. That's what normal parameterlist is for.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    show('index');
}, 4000);
```

Then your function `show` becomes something like this:

```
function show( page ) // pass string as an argument
{
    if ( page == "index" )
    {
    // ...
```

Comment: Funny, I've been trying different settings. When i++ (so to say) the animation goes slow, but without freezing up. When i+2 (or more) the animation freezes, my screen goes grey (in Ubuntu) and then resumes again. Maybe I should look into jQuery in the end.

Comment: Thanks for all the great sidenotes, I'll give those a try shortly. My javascript is under par.

Comment: Thank you for the peer review you did. You are right, the 'this' reference is / was an ugly hack. Just uploaded the site, but still, even though there is an improvement, it's not entirely smooth. Any more ideas?

Comment: Maybe I should look into jQuery and forget about it.

Comment: The problem is probably that you're moving 2 600x450 pictures in the same time. Browsers aren't meant to do that. It would be better with HW acceleration and canvas, but then you can't support older browsers.

Comment: Thanks @galambalazs I'm happy with the result and most people congratulate me with the site, so I guess that's settled.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are advancing your animation every 75 ms. That is ca. 13 steps per second. You need at least 24 steps per second for smooth movement. I recommend 33 ms (ca. 30 steps per second) or 16 ms (60 steps per second). 16 ms is what jQuery uses for its animations (and jQuery is very good at this).

Comment: Tried in dev. but no cigar. The image moves faster, but not smoothly.

Comment: I guess it's my computer, but why? The hardware is old, but no so bad as not to be able to render the images correctly. Is there something I can do to optimize the graphics?

Comment: it's not your computer. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a library to help you achieve that. For example **jQuery** which has some example there: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: +1 for jQuery! Why write the nuts and bolts when you can focus on getting stuff done.

Comment: I know about jQuery but didn't bother to investigate.